# How to iterate over each bit of a byte in Python?

Tags: python, binary, bit-manipulation

Let's say `a=0xF0` and `b=[a list of bits]`. How do I iterate over each bit of `a` so that i can perform a bitwise operation between that bit and a bit in list `b`?

I have tried converting `a` to its binary form using the `bin()` method before looping through it, however, i can no longer perform a bitwise operation as each bit of `a` is now of the string datatype.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can convert the string returned by `bin` to a list of bits (ints of value 0 and 1) and then work with two lists.

Comment: What do you mean by "list of bits"? Is it a list of integers with values 0 or 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bitshift:

```py
a = 0xF0
b = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]

print(bin(a))
# 0b11110000
for idx, bit_in_b in enumerate(b):
    bit_in_a = (a >> idx) & 1
    binary_and_operation = bit_in_a & bit_in_b
    print(bit_in_a, binary_and_operation)

# 0 0
# 0 0
# 0 0
# 0 0
# 1 1
# 1 0
# 1 1
# 1 0
```

Careful to 2 points:

- `a` will be iterated from right to left and b from left to right, but you can change that as needed.
- if `len(b)` != number of bits in `a`, behavior might not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner would be this:

```
bin(int("".join([str(bit) for bit in b]), 2) ^ a)[2:].zfill(max(len(b), (len(bin(a))-2)))
```

It works like so:

- `"".join([str(bit) for bit in b]` converts your list to a string
- `int(..., 2)` converts to a number in base 2
- `^` is the bitwise `xor` (or any other operation you want)
- `bin(...)` converts it back to a binary representation
- `[2:]` drops the `0b` part of the string
- `.zfil(...)` pads the result with zeroes until the result has the same number of bits as the largest of the two inputs, in case the bitwise result starts with zeroes.

Example:

```
a = 0xF0
b = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
result = bin(int("".join([str(bit) for bit in b]), 2) ^ a)[2:].zfill(max(len(b), (len(bin(a))-2)))
print(result)
```

Output:

```
10000010
```